# Weird attribute error

Tags: c#, attributes, compiler-errors

I had this solution working happily and i added this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class metadata : Attribute
{
    string mid;
    string mdescription;
    Dictionary<string, string> mdata;
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    public string description
    {
        get
        {
            return mdescription;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> data
    {
        get
        {
            return mdata;
        }
    }
    public metadata(string thisid, string thisdescription, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] thisdataarray)
    {
        mid = thisid;
        mdescription = thisdescription;
        mdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (thisdataarray != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> thisvaluepair in thisdataarray)
            {
                mdata.Add(thisvaluepair.Key, thisvaluepair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a few declarations of this attribute, all [metadata(null, null)] with no errors. Somehow, when I compile, for each [metadata(null, null)] an "error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" occurs, however with no line or column or file, only the project. What went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the lack of file name, line number, and column number: This is also a problem with optional parameters. I later reported a bug on the issue, see [C# compiler fails to emit file name and line number when reporting compile-time error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763609/c-compiler-fails-to-emit-file-name-and-line-number-when-reporting-compile-time-error). I will go and add a comment on that bug report about the situation with `params`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that KeyValuePair is not supported as attribute parameter type. 
According to the [C# Language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:

- One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int,
  long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
- The type object.
- The type System.Type.
- An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in
  which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility.
- Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

As a workaround you can pass an array of strings where the odd members are keys and even members are values. Then inside the attribute constructor you can create your Dictionary.

Comment: Alternatively, create a new attribute which takes separate (Key, Value) pairs and apply it once for each data item you need to associate with a class.

Answer (score 0):

The way you declared the array is suspicious, I don't think you need the params keyword.  I don't think you want 0 or more keyvaluepair arrays, I think you are looking for a single array with 0 or more entries.  Remove the params keyword, and set the default value of thisdataarray to null.

Comment: i dont think there was a problem. i wrote it after reading msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.100).aspx . Also, I tried your solution and it didnt work :(